# Url Encode - Decode

Tags: php, urlencode

I passed email to my URL like that:

```
http://www.mysite.com?email=external%2Bcustomer%40gmail.com
```

however when print `$_REQUEST` it gives me following output:

```
external^customer%40gmail.com /* console output */
```

I want output like that:

```
external%2Bcustomer%40gmail.com
```

please help me on this

Comment: `<?php echo htmlentities($_REQUEST["email"]); ?>` ?

Comment: echo urlencode($_REQUEST['email']);

Comment: It gives me output like: external^customer@gmail.com i dont want decoded vaules in my email i want output same like as i passed to url.

Comment: thats is because `$_GET` and `$_REQUEST` are already applied with `urldecode()` function. Trying with `Post`, might be it will work.

Comment: i tried htmlentities it gives external^customer@gmail.com plz help me...

Comment: Can I suggest not using `$_REQUEST` unless you absolutely need to, it loads values from multiple sources according to a setting in your php.ini, it's possible for these to overwrite one another and cause unexpected conflicts and has a dependency on your config that is easily missed/forgotten.

Answer (score 4):

If you want output exact as it is passed in URL, try this:

```
print_r(urlencode($_REQUEST['email']));
```

`$_REQUEST` is automatically decoded, so you need to encode it again.

Comment: I have tried this but gives output like          external%5Ecustomer%40gmail.com it replaces %2B with %5E.

Comment: It is strange, because `%2B` means `+` sign, whereas `%5E` is `^` character (so even your first output must be wrong). Don't you have any typo? I've tried it and it works fine.

Comment: Actually in my db email address is saved like external%2Bcustomer%40gmail.com  & when i am trying to match this email then it given me email not matching because %2B replace with ^ first time.

Comment: Peter, i just tried same on my localhost it gives me output that i want like external%2Bcustomer%40gmail.com. is this problem with server or what ?

Comment: I don't know, maybe try to ask another question with code examples and we will try to figure out, what's wrong:)